# Displaying states, counties, cities in a Django App

Tags: python, django, api, geolocation

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction, since I have no formal programming experience nor am I really a developer.  I have a django website which is a directory of individuals and businesses.  The site was created by other devs and now I am managing and have no clue what I am really doing and learning as I go along.  I have been reading everything I can get my hands and have learned a lot in this process but am stuck.

I want to create a page which lists all the US states, and when the user clicks on the states names, they will be directed to a page with all the cities and counties (when they click on the cities or counties, they will see a template page with mostly static content but replace the local data like city or county name with the appropriate information) for that specified state.

I was going to use geodjango or django cities but they are both too complicated (I am not a very experienced, and that is an understatement :).

I am now creating a csv file of the information i want (states/counties/cities/zip codes) which I plan to import to the db and then use models/views/templates to display the data.

I have considered using this api http://www.sba.gov/about-sba-services/7617/ instead of importing the data to my db.

My question is as follows:

What is the best method to accomplish having pages for state, county, city, and zip codes which have relationships so that the cities and zip codes are associated with the counties and states?

How do use http://www.sba.gov/about-sba-services/7617/ api to accomplish the above mentioned and would i still need to import data to DB and create models/views/templates when using api?

I know these are basic questions and I know I should take some classed to learn it but figured maybe I will get lucky and someone will provide a viable answer.  Please keep in mind I have very minimal experience so elaborating on the answers would be helpful.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have built a geolocating app and also found geodjango and django-cities overkill for what I need.

So I used http://www.geonames.org/ and just imported their database in. You can query it just like a regular database if you set you models accordingly. Django-cities does the same thing but I never got it to work and it would import everything. If you need to import just US states and cities then you can leave out the rest by hand or delete them with django after importing everything. And then making your database into a Django fixture so it get reimported every time with just your data.

I found that they have country specific dumps also so your in luck. Just download the US one and set things up. http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/US.zip (this has the cities with additional data) - dont import things you dont need if you want to save space.
And you have to use this together with the admin table which has a ID that the cities database reffers to for State - http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/admin1CodesASCII.txt
(Later if you need to reduce the queries you can merge the tables so cities already has the states.)

If you'd need any other help with this then just ask. It's very easy to do things with those databases. The only confusing thing at first is the linking between the admincodes and city names.

Just model your Django database tables the same way so you can even use Djangos own ORM.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, really helpful, I have created a csv file with the states and cities and a different csv file with the states and the counties like such:

City State Lat Long
AIBONITO PR 18.14 -66.26
ANASCO PR 18.28 -67.14
ANGELES PR 18.28 -66.79
ARECIBO PR 18.45 -66.73

COUNTIES
01003 Baldwin County  AL
01005 Barbour County  AL
01007 Bibb County  AL
01009 Blount County  AL
01011 Bullock County  AL
01013 Butler County  AL
01015 Calhoun County  AL
01017 Chambers County  AL
01019 Cherokee County  AL

Comment: So I have 2 different files and want to import them into the db so I can create the pages and call the data accordingly.  Do you think this is ok or should I do as you suggested above with geonames.

Comment: Just to recap, I would start a new django app and create the models to show have a class for states which would have a child county, city, zip.  And create another class for state counties with a child as counties.  Then use the views to define the data and use a html template to display the data?  Sound about right, I have really no experience with this stuff so I just want to confirm.

Comment: any sample code with details would be really helpful, also, do you have any experience with RESTful Api with django, is that another way to go if I use the http://www.sba.gov/about-sba-services/7617/ api?  I just need the states/counties/cities/zips - thanks again

Comment: The main thing I am stuck on is how to import the data at this point.

Comment: I have already created a cvs file with the data, pretty simple too - just state full name, state abbreviation, county name, and city/zips.  Don't know how to import the data to my project.  I know how to use the python interpreter a little bit, but not sure what to do there, been reading the django book to find the solution

Comment: This depends on your databse of choice. Please make the models and do a syncdb. Then just import data as you would do a regular database. There is going to be no magic there.

Comment: So I finally got it going, but i am having a small issue with getting the links (of the city names) to render on the page without quotation marks (e.g. when the page renders, the links have quotation marks around them like so "Albuquerque").  Not sure how to remove them but have imported the data into db, and finished models and views.  Thank you for your help

Comment: You have probably imported the csv's wrong. There is a way to import things without the quotation marks. I did the same thing at first.

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2345/import_csv_file_directly_into_mysql/

Please read the following - enclosed is the quotes you want to remove I suppose.

Comment: Ok, i got rid of the "", thanks for the info, I just used find and replace and removed the "" from data file and re imported data.  I am however stuck again : )

I cant figure out how to associate states with cities and counties in my models, views and templates.  I have the page of states, and when I click on a state name, I want to display the cities and counties for that state.  I cannot figure out how to pass that information to through the urls.py so that when the user clicks on the state name, they are presented with the correct list of cities and counties with correct meta and title.

Comment: I think I am supposed to use foreign keys and manytomany for the fields i want to associate but then, I don't know how to pass the information to the template and how to filter the cities/counties for the specific state.  Any advice would be appreciated.  Thanks for all your help